# Model Matrix has no effect on Diffuse Shading

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, shader

I've been working through the tutorials [here](https://learnopengl.com/) to learn OpenGL, but I've hit a wall with the code not acting as it should. I'm up to [this](https://learnopengl.com/#!Lighting/Basic-Lighting) point, learning about basic lighting. My code worked, displaying a shaded cube; however, when I tried changing the model matrix, it still displayed the shading as though the cube were at the origin.

To make sure it wasn't just me, I copied the code provided by the tutorial (mostly) and added a single line:

```
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3( 3.0, -1.0, 1.0));
```

...and the cube moved, but the shading stayed the same! Why?

Since it's probably something awful deep inside the code that I'm not properly understanding: here's the code and my shaders. (Again, it's mostly not mine.)
Code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <SOIL/SOIL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/projection.hpp>

#include "Shader.h"
#include "camera.h"


// Function prototypes
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);
void do_movement();

// Window dimensions
const GLuint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

// Camera
Camera  camera(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f));
GLfloat lastX  =  WIDTH  / 2.0;
GLfloat lastY  =  HEIGHT / 2.0;
bool    keys[1024];

// Light attributes
glm::vec3 lightPos(1.2f, 1.0f, 2.0f);

// Deltatime
GLfloat deltaTime = 0.0f;   // Time between current frame and last frame
GLfloat lastFrame = 0.0f;   // Time of last frame

// The MAIN function, from here we start the application and run the game loop
int main()
{
    // Init GLFW
    glfwInit();
    // Set all the required options for GLFW
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    // Create a GLFWwindow object that we can use for GLFW's functions
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Set the required callback functions
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);

    // GLFW Options
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    // Set this to true so GLEW knows to use a modern approach to retrieving function pointers and extensions
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
    glewInit();

    // Define the viewport dimensions
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    // OpenGL options
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);


    // Build and compile our shader program
    Shader* lightingShader = new Shader("lit_vertex_shader", "lit_fragment_shader");
    Shader* lampShader = new Shader("lamp_vertex_shader", "lamp_fragment_shader");


    // Set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and attribute pointers
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,

    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,

     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,

    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f
    };
    // First, set the container's VAO (and VBO)
    GLuint VBO, containerVAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &containerVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(containerVAO);
    // Position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // Normal attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // Then, we set the light's VAO (VBO stays the same. After all, the vertices are the same for the light object (also a 3D cube))
    GLuint lightVAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &lightVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(lightVAO);
    // We only need to bind to the VBO (to link it with glVertexAttribPointer), no need to fill it; the VBO's data already contains all we need.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    // Set the vertex attributes (only position data for the lamp))
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0); // Note that we skip over the normal vectors
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);


    // Game loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
    // Calculate deltatime of current frame
    GLfloat currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
    deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
    lastFrame = currentFrame;

    // Check if any events have been activiated (key pressed, mouse moved etc.) and call corresponding response functions
    glfwPollEvents();
    do_movement();

    // Clear the colorbuffer
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Use cooresponding shader when setting uniforms/drawing objects
    lightingShader->Use();
    GLint objectColorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(lightingShader->getProgram(), "objectColor");
    GLint lightColorLoc  = glGetUniformLocation(lightingShader->getProgram(), "lightColor");
    GLint lightPosLoc    = glGetUniformLocation(lightingShader->getProgram(), "lightPos");
    glUniform3f(objectColorLoc, 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.31f);
    glUniform3f(lightColorLoc,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glUniform3f(lightPosLoc,    lightPos.x, lightPos.y, lightPos.z);


    // Create camera transformations
    glm::mat4 view;
    view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(camera.Zoom, (GLfloat)WIDTH / (GLfloat)HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    // Get the uniform locations
    GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(lightingShader->getProgram(), "model");
    GLint viewLoc  = glGetUniformLocation(lightingShader->getProgram(),  "view");
    GLint projLoc  = glGetUniformLocation(lightingShader->getProgram(),  "projection");
    // Pass the matrices to the shader
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

    // Draw the container (using container's vertex attributes)
    glm::mat4 model;
    //barring a few bits and pieces, following is the only changed line from the tutorial (I think)
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3( 3.0, -1.0, 1.0));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    glBindVertexArray(containerVAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // Also draw the lamp object, again binding the appropriate shader
    lampShader->Use();
    // Get location objects for the matrices on the lamp shader (these could be different on a different shader)
    modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(lampShader->getProgram(), "model");
    viewLoc  = glGetUniformLocation(lampShader->getProgram(), "view");
    projLoc  = glGetUniformLocation(lampShader->getProgram(), "projection");
    // Set matrices
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
    model = glm::mat4();
    model = glm::translate(model, lightPos);
    model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.2f)); // Make it a smaller cube
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    // Draw the light object (using light's vertex attributes)
    glBindVertexArray(lightVAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // Swap the screen buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    // Terminate GLFW, clearing any resources allocated by GLFW.
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// Is called whenever a key is pressed/released via GLFW
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    if (key >= 0 && key < 1024)
    {
    if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
        keys[key] = true;
    else if (action == GLFW_RELEASE)
        keys[key] = false;
    }
}

void do_movement()
{
    // Camera controls
    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_W])
    camera.ProcessKeyboard(FORWARD, deltaTime);
    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_S])
    camera.ProcessKeyboard(BACKWARD, deltaTime);
    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_A])
    camera.ProcessKeyboard(LEFT, deltaTime);
    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_D])
    camera.ProcessKeyboard(RIGHT, deltaTime);
    if(keys[GLFW_KEY_SPACE]) {
    if(keys[GLFW_KEY_LEFT_SHIFT] or keys[GLFW_KEY_RIGHT_SHIFT]) {
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(DOWN, deltaTime);
    } else {
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(UP, deltaTime);
    }
    }
}

bool firstMouse = true;
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    if (firstMouse)
    {
    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;
    firstMouse = false;
    }

    GLfloat xoffset = xpos - lastX;
    GLfloat yoffset = lastY - ypos;  // Reversed since y-coordinates go from bottom to left

    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;

    camera.ProcessMouseMovement(xoffset, yoffset);
}

void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    camera.ProcessMouseScroll(yoffset);
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;

out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 FragPos;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    vec3 fragPos = vec3(model*vec4(position, 1.0f));
    Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model)))*normal;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 FragPos;

out vec4 color;

uniform vec3 objectColor;
uniform vec3 lightColor;
uniform vec3 lightPos;

void main()
{

    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - FragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;
    float ambi = 0.05;
    vec3 ambient = ambi * lightColor;
    color = vec4((diffuse + ambient) * objectColor, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Translations do not change the shadings from a directional light source.

Comment: @dari Why not? If it was to the left of the light source, and now it's to the right, different sides of the cube should be shaded.

Comment: From glancing at your code, it looks like the shader's `lightPos` is expected to be in model-space, i.e. relative to the model. That's why it looks the same. You have lightPos in world-space. You need to transform it by the inverse of the model matrix in your C++ code before you pass it to the shader. If you're following a tutorial I would suggest you keep going and they'll probably get to how to do this at some point.

Comment: @dbandstra Thank you, that fixed it! I'll add an answer and credit you soon, but I do have one question: why does `lightpos` need to be in model space (from world space multiplied by inverse model matrix) if, in the vertex shader, I convert `FragPos` into world space (by multiplying from model space by the model matrix)?

Comment: @CalvinSchwa Sorry I didn't see that part of the vertex shader. I think my last comment is irrelevant. Can you check the use of `fragPos` vs. `FragPos` in your vertex shader? It might be that you're never setting `FragPos` at all?

Comment: @dbandstra I fixed the fragPos vs FragPos typo, but without multiplying `lightPos` by the inverse of `model` it still displays incorrectly. So... irrelevant or not, your comment fixed my problem. That said, I'm now even more confused as to why the fix _worked_.

Comment: @CalvinSchwa what if you replace the last line of the vertex shader with this? `Normal = vec3(model * vec4(normal, 0.0f));` not sure why you were inverting the model matrix there.

Comment: @dbandstra Seems to make no difference -- they both display the same thing. I copied that particular line from the tutorial, but it's meant to accomplish the same thing -- transforming the normals based on rotation and scaling, but not translation (of which there is none here yet anyway). Testing it now, neither one seems to handle rotation correctly.

Comment: @dbandstra Wait, remvoing the weird code and using yours in the vertex shader, _plus_ removing the inverse matrix call, seems to have fixed it. I'll do some thinking on that. Thank you tons for the help!

Comment: @CalvinSchwa Glad to hear it. I should point out that in practice you shouldn't be doing these transformations in your shaders at all. Ultimately you should be transforming the light pos into model-space in your C++ code, so that your shaders can operate exclusively in model-space. I hesitate to mention this because the tutorial probably gets to it eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out a while back, but had been hesitating to put an answer up since it's probably not helpful for anyone else. It took a few hours (!), but here it is.
(Note that I had already corrected the typo mentioned in the comments above; FragPos is now correctly capitalized.)

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;

out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 FragPos;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    vec3 FragPos = vec3(model*vec4(position, 1.0f));
    Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model)))*normal;
}
```

See anything wrong? No?
...yeah, it's redeclaring FragPos as its own local variable and not passing anything out. At least, I think so. In any case, changing `vec3 FragPos = ...` to `FragPos = ...` fixed it. All my other 'fixes' only seemed to work because they weren't moving things quite enough to make it clear that FragPos was always 0.

Thanks anyway to dbandstra for the help.